# Reading and adding a generic list with a C# application from a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I need to pull data from the CSV file for my analysis to be done all the time. 
The file size has values close to 1 GB and total number of rows to read 20-30 million units

> Expectations : As time to finish the job in less time and to look for
>   a more optimum solution in memory usage.

Can you review the code and results I wrote and advise?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reading Start ");
    Stopwatch Okuma = new Stopwatch();
    Okuma.Start();
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\QuantMoment\Documents\Python_ML\FXDemo\EURUSD.csv";
    List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
    Okuma.Stop();
    Stopwatch AdetZaman = new Stopwatch();
    AdetZaman.Start();
    int adet = lines.Count();
    AdetZaman.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Number of rows : {adet} ");
    List<TickData> TickListem = new List<TickData>();
    Console.WriteLine("Starting to add to list ......");
    Stopwatch Listeleme = new Stopwatch();
    Listeleme.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < adet; i++)
    {
        TickListem.Add(new TickData(lines[i].ToString()));
    }

    Listeleme.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"CSV Reading Total Time(sec)                 : {Okuma.Elapsed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Number of rows Total Time(sec)              : {AdetZaman.Elapsed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Total duration of adding a Generic list     : {Listeleme.Elapsed}");
}

public class TickData
{
    public DateTime Z {get;set;}
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }

    public TickData(string Liste)
    {
        string[] arrayListe = Liste.Split(',');
        this.Z = DateTime.Parse(arrayListe[0]);
        this.Bid = double.Parse(arrayListe[1]);
        this.Ask = double.Parse(arrayListe[2]);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Tarih : {Z}\tBid : {Bid}\tAsk : {Ask}";
    }
}
```

Results

```
Reading Start
Number of rows : 23440779
Starting to add to list ......
CSV Reading Total Time(sec)                 : 00:00:11.3246076
Number of rows Total Time(sec)              : 00:00:00.0000620
Total duration of adding a Generic list     : 00:01:17.0002302
```

Comment: As you are asking for a codereview, why not ask it on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)? :) For the rest, it seems the data you are expecting is a rather simplified form of csv, and you seem to be sure that every row has exactly 3 columns

Comment: You also seem to assume that there are no comments or quoted strings in your data, that only commas will be used for separating fields, and that they will never be escaped. All those assumptions are, in general, false.

Comment: @DourHighArch In general, yes that is false. But based on how he's parsing the data, he has only numeric and date values, likely generated by other software, so the assumption seems reasonable in this specific case. However, you are correct to imply it would be much better to use a dedicated CSV parser.

Comment: I'm not an expert on software like you guys :)
I'm trying to learn from scratch in my own efforts. What I wanted to ask was a simple matter, but I couldn't tell you. 
It was a question of time to get the job done in less time and to learn a better coding ability in terms of memory usage. Maybe I asked the question in the wrong place, but I'm a beginner, shouldn't you be so cruel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should **dramatically** reduce the total time and memory use, at the cost of it no longer making sense to measure the read, count, and list operations separately, as they now all happen as the file is streamed from disk:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Reading Start {DateTime.Now}");
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\QuantMoment\Documents\Python_ML\FXDemo\EURUSD.csv";
    int adet = 0;
    List<TickData> TickListem = new List<TickData>();

    var Okuma = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath); //this just opens the file, doesn't really start to read from it yet 
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        //the biggest cost here BY FAR will be parsing the fields from the line, rather than adding to the list.
        TickListem.Add(new TickData(line));
        adet++;
    }
    Okuma.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Number of rows               : {adet} ");
    Console.WriteLine($"CSV Reading Total Time(sec)  : {Okuma.Elapsed}");
}
```

You could probably improve it further by using a dedicated CSV parser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I applied the solution you suggested.
When I implement the Class 

Number of rows: 23440779
CSV Reading Total Time (sec): 00:00:49.7992275


When I change the Class structure to struct 

Number of rows: 23440779
CSV Reading Total Time (sec): 00:00:40.5540547

For now, 9 seconds to be profitable. I hope there will be no shortage of technical use between Class and Struct.

Comment: Classes and structs do have different behaviors in .Net. I wouldn't say one is better or worse for every situation, but they are different.